How to assemble K local matrix for a hexahedron cell in a piecewise linear fashion?

import meshio
from funcs import hexaBasis 
import sympy as sp 
from sympy import diff, symbols 
from scipy.optimize import root
import numpy as np 

x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
# Define quadrature points and weights for a hexahedron (2x2x2 Gaussian quadrature)
quadrature_points = [
    [-1/np.sqrt(3), -1/np.sqrt(3), -1/np.sqrt(3)],
    [ 1/np.sqrt(3), -1/np.sqrt(3), -1/np.sqrt(3)],
    [ 1/np.sqrt(3),  1/np.sqrt(3), -1/np.sqrt(3)],
    [-1/np.sqrt(3),  1/np.sqrt(3), -1/np.sqrt(3)],
    [-1/np.sqrt(3), -1/np.sqrt(3),  1/np.sqrt(3)],
    [ 1/np.sqrt(3), -1/np.sqrt(3),  1/np.sqrt(3)],
    [ 1/np.sqrt(3),  1/np.sqrt(3),  1/np.sqrt(3)],
    [-1/np.sqrt(3),  1/np.sqrt(3),  1/np.sqrt(3)]
]
weights = [1.0] * 8  # All weights are 1 for 2x2x2 Gaussian quadrature
mesh = meshio.read("cube_of_hexahedrons_dolfinx.xdmf")
cell_block0 = mesh.cells[0]
cell0 = cell_block0.data[0]
nodes_cell0 = mesh.points[cell0]

global tab_points
tab_points = [
    [0, 0, 0],  # Node 0
    [1, 0, 0],  # Node 1
    [1, 1, 0],  # Node 2
    [0, 1, 0],  # Node 3
    [0, 0, 1],  # Node 4
    [1, 0, 1],  # Node 5
    [1, 1, 1],  # Node 6
    [0, 1, 1]   # Node 7
]

def global_to_local(x, y, z, tab_points):
    def func(xi_eta_zeta):
        xi, eta, zeta = xi_eta_zeta
        N = [
            (1 - xi) * (1 - eta) * (1 - zeta) / 8,
            (1 + xi) * (1 - eta) * (1 - zeta) / 8,
            (1 + xi) * (1 + eta) * (1 - zeta) / 8,
            (1 - xi) * (1 + eta) * (1 - zeta) / 8,
            (1 - xi) * (1 - eta) * (1 + zeta) / 8,
            (1 + xi) * (1 - eta) * (1 + zeta) / 8,
            (1 + xi) * (1 + eta) * (1 + zeta) / 8,
            (1 - xi) * (1 + eta) * (1 + zeta) / 8,
        ]
        x_calc = sum(N[i] * tab_points[i][0] for i in range(8))
        y_calc = sum(N[i] * tab_points[i][1] for i in range(8))
        z_calc = sum(N[i] * tab_points[i][2] for i in range(8))
        return [x_calc - x, y_calc - y, z_calc - z]

    xi_eta_zeta_initial_guess = [0, 0, 0]
    solution = root(func, xi_eta_zeta_initial_guess)
    return solution.x


def jacobian(Φs, nodes_local, hexahedron_nodes):
    ML = sp.zeros(3, 8)
    MR = sp.zeros(8,3)

    for i in range(8):
        ML[0,i] = diff(Φs[i], x).subs({x: nodes_local[i][0], y: nodes_local[i][1], z: nodes_local[i][2]})
        ML[1,i] = diff(Φs[i], y).subs({x: nodes_local[i][0], y: nodes_local[i][1], z: nodes_local[i][2]})
        ML[2,i] = diff(Φs[i], z).subs({x: nodes_local[i][0], y: nodes_local[i][1], z: nodes_local[i][2]})

    for i in range(3):
        MR[0,i] = hexahedron_nodes[0][i]
        MR[1,i] = hexahedron_nodes[1][i]
        MR[2,i] = hexahedron_nodes[2][i]
        MR[3,i] = hexahedron_nodes[3][i]
        MR[4,i] = hexahedron_nodes[4][i]
        MR[5,i] = hexahedron_nodes[5][i]
        MR[6,i] = hexahedron_nodes[6][i]
        MR[7,i] = hexahedron_nodes[7][i]

    return ML * MR

Φs = hexaBasis()
gradΦs = []
NBs = []



nodes_local =[]
for i in range(8):
    nodes_local.append( global_to_local(nodes_cell0[i][0], nodes_cell0[i][1], nodes_cell0[i][2], tab_points ) ) 


for i in range(8):
    gradΦ0 = diff(Φs[0],x).subs({x: nodes_local[i][0], y: nodes_local[i][1], z: nodes_local[i][2], }) 
    + diff(Φs[0],y).subs({x: nodes_local[i][0], y: nodes_local[i][1], z: nodes_local[i][2], }) 
    + diff(Φs[0],z).subs({x: nodes_local[i][0], y: nodes_local[i][1], z: nodes_local[i][2], })
    gradΦs.append(gradΦ0)


M = sp.zeros(8)
for i in range(8):
    M[i,0] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[0]
    M[i,1] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[1]
    M[i,2] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[2]
    M[i,3] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[3]
    M[i,4] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[4]
    M[i,5] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[5]
    M[i,6] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[6]
    M[i,7] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[7]


J = jacobian(Φs, nodes_local, nodes_cell0)

M = M * J.det()


print(M)
print('done...')

'''
[1.93359375000000, 1.93359375000000, 1.45019531250000, 1.45019531250000, 1.45019531250000, 1.45019531250000, 1.08764648437500, 1.08764648437500]
'''

'''
dolfinx output of the same K local from the same mesh of cell
[[ 8.33333333e-02 -3.95818496e-18  2.67916521e-18 ...  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [-5.22280515e-18  1.66666667e-01 -2.08333333e-02 ...  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]

'''


There seems to be something not quite right yet. The local K matrix from the same cell0 for the same mesh xdmf that was imported here is reporting different values than I have. Seems that things maybe need to be integrated some way. Ideally I need to match the dolfinx values within a small margin. So far I attempted to construct the hexahedron in a piecewise linear fashion. Why are my results so far away from what dolfinx says for the same cell?
Is there a way to integrate the gradients over the domain?

I don't think anyone can help you if you don't describe (i) what exactly it is you are computing, (ii) what the code produces, (iii) what it is you are expecting, (iv) what you have already done to figure out where the discrepancy is coming from. All you provide here is a large code dump with no explanation. You are expecting others not only to execute your code, but also to divine what it is you are expecting to happen.

(i) K is being computed in piecewise linear form (title), (ii) The code produces values for K, (iii) correct outputs from dolfinx are provided to match with, (iv) I built code that is within range of dolfinx's values that need to come down some. The code I made is self documenting short and simple to read, sorry you feel that way. What I expect to happen is maybe get some idea on why my values are too large from someone that knows what they are doing.

In light of the info req. I am saying that a cube can be created in dolfinx,     mesh = dolfinx.mesh.create_unit_cube(MPI.COMM_WORLD, 4, 4, 4, cell_type=dolfinx.mesh.CellType.hexahedron)     and the basis functions I used to formulate my results posted in comments at the bottom came from symfem. My aim is to keep it short and simple so I can not show how this is done however one can convert dolfinx's csr matrix to a dense one to export a local K from dolfinx to compare with.

Is your problem computing the stiffness matrix of an element of assembling several elements?

Here a local K for a single hexahedron is assembled. M is a local K matrix of that hexahedron. I exported the first row of the same local K for the same element from dolfinx to look at to see how close is my assembly to dolfinx's. My results for the first row of M (which is a K local) are printed right above that. There is a discrepancy between this algorithm and dolfinx's to work through. If the assembly is done correctly the two result sets will match.

Just FYI in dolfix software one can build a bilinear form: ufl.inner(ufl.grad(u), ufl.grad(v)) * ufl.dx, of the base gradients which is what I aim to accomplish in my code. The bilinear form gets assembled into K.  What is u and v (or nu) is described in a book by Mark S. Gockenbach's "Understanding the Finite Element Method" somewhere near chapter 3 he starts to explain u and v.

All I'm saying is that all of this information should have been in the question to begin with. You're asking too much of people if you say "my code is self-documenting, just read through it".

Pardon me, I the means of keeping things short and as simple as possible I was waiting for questions to be asked so that background information could be given instead of making a problem that is already difficult for me tougher on other people.

Explaining the problem in plain English is not making something tougher but the opposite.


Φs = hexaBasis()
gradΦs = []

nodes_local = []
for i in range(8):
    nodes_local.append(global_to_local(nodes_cell0[i][0], nodes_cell0[i][1], nodes_cell0[i][2], tab_points))

for i in range(8):
    gradΦ0 = diff(Φs[0], x).subs({x: quadrature_points[i][0], y: quadrature_points[i][1], z: quadrature_points[i][2]}) 
    + diff(Φs[0], y).subs({x: quadrature_points[i][0], y: quadrature_points[i][1], z: quadrature_points[i][2]}) 
    + diff(Φs[0], z).subs({x: quadrature_points[i][0], y: quadrature_points[i][1], z: quadrature_points[i][2]})
    gradΦs.append(gradΦ0)

M_k = sp.zeros(8)
for i in range(8):
    M_k[i, 0] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[0]
    M_k[i, 1] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[1]
    M_k[i, 2] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[2]
    M_k[i, 3] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[3]
    M_k[i, 4] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[4]
    M_k[i, 5] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[5]
    M_k[i, 6] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[6]
    M_k[i, 7] = gradΦs[i] * gradΦs[7]

# Integrate each element of M_k symbolically using SymPy
M_k_integrated = sp.zeros(8, 8)

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        M_k_integrated[i, j] = M_k[i, j].integrate((x, x_min, x_max), (y, y_min, y_max), (z, z_min, z_max))

# Convert elements of M_k_integrated to floating-point numbers
M_k_integrated_decimal = M_k_integrated.evalf()

# Print the integrated M_k in decimal format
print("Integrated M_k:")
for row in M_k_integrated_decimal.tolist():
    print([float(elem) for elem in row])


This is so far a tentative answer to the question of how to integrate the system. It provides values similar to other FEM software however the results are not identical. So far is there is anything incorrect here I am not aware of it at this time.
The limits of integration are the limits of the element in the global reference frame.

For it to be better suited as an answer you could update your question with the problem that you are trying to solve and the issue at hand. The same goes for the answer, you could explain what was the approach used to solve it.

I added a comment about the missing integration as it relates to the original code.

The limits of the integration are mapped to the global reference frame. Since that it wasn't inquired about I feel the need to say so.
